# Speeding up .ix in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to speed up the following code.  'db' is a dictionary of DataFrames.  Is there a better/different way to structure things which would speed this up?

```
for date in dates:                           # 3,800 days
    for instrument in instruments:           # 100 instruments
        s = instrument.ticker                         
        current_bar = db[s].ix[date]
        # (current_bar.xxx then gets used for difference calculations.)
```

Here are the results:

```
%timeit speedTest()
1 loops, best of 3: 1min per loop
```

This is for each individual call:

```
%timeit current_bar = db[s].ix[date]
10000 loops, best of 3: 154 µs per loop
```

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: try using [`.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply), with `axis=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think a dict of dataframes is a good idea. Try structure all dataframes in one -- stack vertically and use key as index/ a level of multiindex.

Comment: That's what I was thinking might be the issue as well.  Since I'm new to python and pandas, I'll have to do a bit more research on this ... as I don't really understand the structure you describe.   Thanks